# IOS: Reload view from another view controller in stack

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, setneedsdisplay

I have a hamburger menu in a container as well as a target view controller.  When I choose a row in the menu, the menu disappears to reveal the target view controller.  However, I would like the target view controller to reload in order to reflect a change in the data.  Right now, neither viewdidload or viewwillappear seem to be firing as the VC is already in the stack.

Many answers on SO suggest `[self.view setNeedsDisplay]` will force a reload but I can't figure out how to call setNeedsDisplay from the menu vc.

What is the preferred method to force  reload of a view controller already in the stack from another view controller?

Thanks

Comment: you can achieve that via _notification_ or via _delegate_, whichever suits you better.

Comment: The first view controller table view basically pops the second one to the top of the stack using the tableview delegate method.  But I don't know how to face a reload.